# Trying to test if the given string is a palindrome by words

Tags: python, stack, palindrome

Hi i'm trying to achieve this output. I'm trying to see if the string is a palindrome by comparing the first word and the last word, second word and the second last word.

King, are you glad you are king is a palindrome (or that's the outcome i'm trying to achieve) as the 1st word is similar to the last word (which is king), the second word is similar to the second last word (which is are), the third word is similar to the third last word (which is you). hence, the output should be true. (this is the requirement of my assignment)

Output i'm trying to achieve: [True, False]
Output i got: [False]

Comment: It is not a palindrome actually

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `split` in order to word-wise comparison.

In addition, take out `' '` from `bad_character` and fixing some indentation will do:

```
def palindrome_word(a_str):
    outputlist = []
    bad_character = ['?', ',']
    for element in a_str:
        for words in bad_character:
            element = element.replace(words, '')
        element = element.lower().split()
        outputlist.append(element == element[::-1])
    return outputlist
```

Or using `re`:

```
import re

def palindrome_word_re(a_str):
    outputlist = []
    for element in a_str:
        element = element.lower()
        words = re.findall('\w+', element)
        outputlist.append(words == words[::-1])
    return outputlist
```

Both outputs:

```
palindrome_word(my_string)
palindrome_word_re(my_string)

[True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```py
def palindrome_word(a_str):
    outputlist = []
    bad_character = ['?', ',']
    for element in a_str:
        for words in bad_character:
            element = element.replace(words, '')
        element = element.lower()
        result = (element.split())[::-1] == element.split()
        outputlist.append(result)
    return outputlist

my_string=["King, are you glad you are king?", "Hello Bye"]
print(palindrome_word(my_string))
```

OUTOUT

```
[True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach -

```
def palindrome_word(a_str):
    import re
    outputlist = []
    for element in a_str:
        str_arr = re.findall('\w+', element.lower())
        is_palindrome = True
        for i in range(int(len(str_arr)/2)):
            if str_arr[i] != str_arr[-i-1]:
                is_palindrome = False
                break
        outputlist.append(is_palindrome)
    return outputlist

my_string=["King, are you glad you are king?", "Hello Bye"]
print(palindrome_word(my_string))
```

Output

```
[True, False]
```